Confused about a possible asymmetry between $\land$ and $\lor$ in proof theory
Currently, I believe two things (please correct me if I'm wrong): $\def\f{\phi} \def\y{\psi} \def\LLL{\mathcal{L}} \def\S{\Sigma}$
given sentences $\f,\y$ in the language $\LLL$, and a theory $\S$, we have that

$\S \vdash \f\land \y$ if and only if $\S\vdash \f$ and $\S\vdash \y$.

Proof: for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction, simply use the deduction rule
$$\frac{\f\land\y}{\f}$$
or any equivalent. For the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, write a proof of $\f$, a proof of $\y$ and use
$$\frac{\f,\y}{\f\land\y}.$$

We may have $\S\vdash \f\lor \y$ without either $\S\vdash \f$ or $\S\vdash\y$.

Proof: a simple example is $S = \{ (a = b) \lor (a = c)\}$. Another example is $\f\lor \neg \f$ for any unprovable statement $\f$.

Am I wrong? The asymmetry somewhat bothers me. I have been able to find a post where $(1)$ is shown for a maximally consistent set of sentences, which may be strage to ask if the result holds in general.

In fact, it seems to me that these hold if $\vdash$ is substituted with $\models$: we could have $\Sigma\models \phi\lor\psi$ without $\Sigma\models\phi$ or $\Sigma\models\psi$ if a single models yields (only) $\phi$ while the rest yield $\phi\lor\psi$. I guess the substitution of $\vdash$ by $\models$ would also follow from completeness.

You are correct, in classical logic we don't have this symmetry. You might be interested in intuitionistic logic, which does have this and some other nice proof-theoretic properties.

This is called the disjunction property (for the empty context) and is generally a feature of constructive logics. The real duality is that we have $\phi \lor \psi \vdash \theta$ if and only if $\phi \vdash \theta$ and $\psi \vdash \theta$, so $\lor$ behaves like a coproduct and $\land$ like a product.

You're only dualizing part of the expression you're looking at: the dual to $$\varphi\vdash\psi\wedge\theta\quad\iff\quad \varphi\vdash\psi \mbox{ and }\varphi\vdash\theta$$ is $$\psi\vee\theta\vdash\varphi\quad\iff\quad \psi\vdash\varphi\mbox{ and }\theta\vdash\varphi,$$ which indeed is also true (in classical logic anyways). That is, you have to also flip the direction of $\vdash$.
To complete the picture, note that despite the second biimplication above we may have $\psi\wedge\theta\vdash\varphi$ without $\psi\vdash\varphi$ or $\theta\vdash\varphi$. This is the dual of the "asymmetry" you observe, so everything is in fact nicely symmetric ... as long as we look at it the right way. (Note that one expositionally useful trick here is the shift from theories to sentences, which makes $\vdash$-flipping easier to think about.)

'and' is to be flipped to 'or' in the second biimplication.

@TankutBeygu No it's not. From "$\psi\vdash\varphi$ or $\theta\vdash\varphi$" we cannot conclude "$\psi\vee\theta\vdash\varphi$." For example, let $\psi=\varphi$ and $\theta=\neg\varphi$; we always have "$\psi\vdash\varphi$ or $\theta\vdash\varphi$" but we don't have "$\psi\vee\theta\vdash\varphi$" unless $\varphi$ is a tautology.

@NoahSchweber  I conjecture that Tankut Beygu's comment was intended to ask why the proposed symmetry changes $\land$ to $\lor$ on the left of  $\iff$ but doesn't change"and" to "or" on the right. I'd explain that by saying that the symmetry is a property of the object language, so we flip object-language operations but not metalanguage ones. This explanation works better for a sequent calculus, where $\vdash$ (or another notation for the same thing) is part of the object language and so dedrves to be flipped.

@AndreasBlass That's a good explanation and plausible interpretation; since the comment was phrased as a statement, I just took it that way.

As I understand, it refers to sort of disjunction elimination in NK. If so, I think there is some unnaturalness about that rule. Anyway, you're right.
